# cannot display value correctly in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've 2 fields with same data type `varchar(200)` in mysql but when I input the same value (3" x 3 table) in HTML (the input type is text and textarea) and no problem found in mysql, but when I select the data and display in HTML form, only the textarea can display the full description (3" x 3 table) and the value in input type (text) is 3 without " x 3 table, so i have no idea on this but the value can display when I `echo $row['desc1']` not sure why this cannot be displayed in html

```
$r12=$row['desc1'];
<td><input type="text" id="r1-2" name="r1-2" maxlength="200" style="width: 99%;" value="<?php echo $r12; ?>" /></td>
```

(php version is 5.3.8, mysql is 5.5.16).

Comment: You should escape the content before echo

Comment: Just for fun, put in this description in your database: `"><script>alert('Nice XSS injection you have there!');</script>` See what happens.

Comment: when i input this, i got "Could not update data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Nice XSS injection you have there!');', pono1='0', pod1='', qty1='', up' at line 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `htmlentities` around `$row['desc1']` as `echo htmlentities($row['desc1'])`.

Comment: no matter echo $row['desc1']; or echo htmlentities($row['desc1']); the value can be displayed correctly, the problem is, cannot display in html input text field?

Comment: issue is that your string contains " thats why part after double quotes is striped off. htmlentities() will not truncate string

Comment: Yes, you are right, the problem has been fixed, but should i concern when input with ; in the field?